# Javascript/jQuery Keypress logging

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to log the key presses on a specific page, trying to implement an 'Easter egg' type functionality where when the correct keys are pressed in the correct order it triggers and event.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, even though another answer has been accepted, I'm going to throw one out there anyway.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var easterEgg = 'egg';
    var eggLength = easterEgg.length;
    var keyHistory = '';
    var match;
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            keyHistory += String.fromCharCode(e.which)
            match = keyHistory.match(easterEgg); 
            if(match) {
                alert(match);
                keyHistory = match =  '';
            } else if (keyHistory.length > 30) {
                keyHistory = keyHistory.substr((keyHistory.length - eggLength - 1));
            }
        });
});
```

When you ultimately type 'egg' (for this example), you will get an alert, and the key history will reset.

**EDIT:** *Updated the code to truncate the string if it gets too long.*

Comment: More elegant so have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the exact keypress codes, I borrowed from Hans Kov's answer. I would use an array like a stack and just push a new keypress onto the stack, then pop them off to check for correct order.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var keypresses = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      body.bind('keypress', function(event) {
        switch(event.keyCode) {
          case 40:
            keypresses.push('down');
          break;
          case 38:
            keypresses.push('up');
        }
  
        checkForEasterEgg(keypresses);
      });
    });
  
    function checkForEasterEgg(keyArray) {
      var length = keyArray.length;
      for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // using keyArray.pop(), check if order matches up up down down left right left right b a
        if (easterEggPassed) {
          console.log('30 lives, woohoo!');
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Although, I always find drect use of literals (e.g.40, 38) is better replaced by some sort of constant/object literal as per my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In such circumstances it might also be useful to be able to check for the ctl/alt/shift keys:

```
if (e.altKey) {
}

if (e.ctrlKey) {
}

if (e.shiftKey) {
}
```

For keypress codes, the following object literal should help:

```
var Key =
{
    BACKSPACE: 8,
    TAB: 9,
    ENTER: 13,
    ESC: 27,
    PAGEUP: 33,
    PAGEDOWN: 34,
    END: 35,
    HOME: 36,
    LEFT: 37,
    UP: 38,
    RIGHT: 39,
    DOWN: 40,
    HELP: 47,
    H: 72,
    K: 75,
    N: 78,
    R: 82,
    NUMERIC_PLUS: 107,
    F1: 112,
    F2: 113,
    F3: 114,
    F4: 115,
    F5: 116,
    F6: 117,
    F7: 118,
    F8: 119,
    F9: 120,
    F10: 121,
    F11: 122,
    F12: 123,
    PLUS: 187,
    MINUS: 189,
    V: 86
}
```

So instead of:

```
  switch(event.keyCode) { 
    case 40: 
      keypresses.push('down'); 
    break; 
    case 38: 
      keypresses.push('up'); 
  }
```

We can say:

```
switch(event.keyCode) { 
    case Key.DOWN: 
        keypresses.push('down'); 
        break; 
    case Key.UP: 
        keypresses.push('up'); 
        break; 
}
```

This promotes self documenting code, and is more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I have earlier used this code to use the up/down arrows to scroll through a list, it should be relativly easy to extend this to check for a certain key combo.

```
$("#SearchInput").keydown(function(e){
  switch(e.which) { 
     // User pressed "up" arrow
     case 38:
        navigate('up');
     break;
     // User pressed "down" arrow
     case 40:
        navigate('down');
     break;
     // User pressed "enter"
     case 13:
        if(currentUrl != '') {
           window.location = currentUrl;
        }
     break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$(document).keyup( function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("You pressed escape");
    }
});
```

This captures key presses on the whole page not just a specific element.

[This blog post](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/) details how to capture CTRL+Key shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

here's an easy way to require the ctrl key to be held down while the user enters a sequence of characters. a bit easier than some of the responses. in the case below pressing and holding ctrl key while typing "quack" (no quotes) will trigger the alert. hth someone, someday.

```
     var easterEgg = [81, 85, 65, 67, 75]; //quack
     var eggLength = easterEgg.length;
     var currentPosition = 0;
     $(document).keydown(function (e) {
         if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == easterEgg[currentPosition]) {
             e.preventDefault();
             if (++currentPosition == eggLength) {
                 currentPosition = 0;
                 alert('oh yeah, right there');
             }
         } else {
             currentPosition = 0;
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

**This maybe?**

```
var seq = "rainbow"
var input = ""
window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    input += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)

    for (var i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] != seq[i] && input[i] != undefined) {
            input = ""
        }
    }

    if (input == seq) {
        alert("EASTER EGG!")

        input = ""
    }
})
```