# jQuery detect keystrokes and set variables accordingly

Tags: jquery, variables, reset, keystroke

I have created a rudimentary EasterEgg within my code to activate when the following keystrokes are made (not simultaneously) `Enter + c + o + l + o + r + s` with the following code:

```
isEnter = 0; isC = 0; isO = 0; isL = 0; isR = 0; isS = 0;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which==13) isEnter = 1; if(e.which==67) isC = 1; if(e.which==79) isO = 1; 
    if(e.which==76) isL = 1; if(e.which==82) isR = 1; if(e.which==83) isS = 1;
    ColorMap();
});

function ColorMap(){
  if(isEnter==1 && isC==1 && isO==1 && isL==1 && isR==1 && isS==1){
     //DO FUNCTION//
     isEnter = 0; isC = 0; isO = 0; isL = 0; isR = 0; isS = 0; //SET VARS BACK TO 0
  };
};
```

I need to add reset functionality to the keydown function to reset all variables if something other than those keys are pressed... that way they have to press `Enter + c + o + l + o + r + s` or the statement gets reset and they have to start again...(this will make the 'EasterEgg' harder to get to [or at least less likely to get to by fluke or random keystrokes]).

Comment: so many variables! thank god ur word is having just 6 chars

Comment: @sadmicrowave - I added a solution below where you don't need to worry about character codes at all, you can use any string pretty easily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to check for these in order, as well. Right now, you could push the keys in any order and still activate the Easter Egg. `Enter + lorocs` for example.

I'd store the values you are looking for in order, like this:

```
//       Enter, c, o, l, o, r, s
var keys = [13,67,79,76,79,82,83];
```

Then, you can just keep track of where the user is in the sequence:

```
var nextKey = 0;
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    if (key === keys[nextKey])
        nextKey++;

    ColorMap();
});
```

This will increment `nextKey` every time you match the next key that you are looking for in the sequence. The `nextKey` variable starts at the 0 index, which means we start looking for `Enter`. Now, we need to check for the end condition in the `ColorMap` function.

```
function ColorMap() {
  var maxKeyIndex = keys.length - 1;
  if(nextKey >= maxKeyIndex) {
     //DO FUNCTION//

     nextKey = 0;
  }
}
```

This solution should allow you to change the special sequence in the `keys` variable without requiring a change elsewhere in the code.

**EDIT:**
If you want the answer to be contiguous, as you probably do, then you can reset the `nextKey` variable when the match fails.

```
if (key === keys[nextKey])
    nextKey++;
else
    nextKey = 0;
```

For extra credit, you could switch this to use a string to hold the easter egg, then `String.fromCharCode` to convert it to the character code that `e.which` returns.

Comment: You could force the Easter Egg keys to have to be contiguous by setting the nextKey counter back to zero if the character doesn't match.

Comment: Certainly. I intended to do that at first, but forgot.

Comment: @EndangeredMassa - this is exactly what I'm looking for. @Pointy - I need to add that functionality also...it seems like adding:


if(key != keys[nextKey]) nextKey = 0; should do the trick but for some reason its not working.

Comment: @EndangeredMassa's Post Edit - dont you need { } around your IF condition's function to make it work? i.e. if(key===keys[nextKey]){nextKey++}else{nextKey=0};

?

Comment: If-else doesn't require brackets. If you don't use them, it just considers the next line when executing. You can certainly add them, though.

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar easter egg question recently, so I'll just point you to that one.

It takes a different approach that what you're doing, and it doesn't need to be reset.

[Javascript/jQuery Keypress logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297524/javascript-jquery-keypress-logging/)

**EDIT:** Here's an updated version that keeps the key history from getting too long.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var easterEgg = 'egg';
    var eggLength = easterEgg.length;
    var keyHistory = '';
    var match;
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            keyHistory += String.fromCharCode(e.which)
            match = keyHistory.match(easterEgg); 
            if(match) {
                alert(match);
                keyHistory = match = '';
            } else if (keyHistory.length > 30) {
                keyHistory = keyHistory.substr((keyHistory.length - eggLength - 1));
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: `+1` gr8, i like ur answer on tht post. Only thing is, lets say user presses thousand keys without pressing the combination for easter egg, then `keyHistory` will be huge. Isn' it?

Comment: Good point. In fact, I was just thinking that, so I updated the code. Will post it in a second. (Both here and there.)

Comment: :), now thts fine. The only point remaining is, in: `keyHistory = keyHistory.substr((keyHistory.length - eggLength - 1));`  i guess, u can replace `keyHistory.length` with 30 , as you have already hardcoded tht.

Comment: @Rakesh - Very true. You could hardcode it to prevent another lookup of the length. `else if (keyHistory.length > 30) { keyHistory = keyHistory.substr((30 - eggLength - 1));}`

Comment: I like that you can store the easter egg in a string.

Comment: Yeah, a string coupled with `String.fromCharCode()` makes things nice and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well currently you're going to let your users press the magic keys in any order, which wouldn't be very much fun.  I'd put the magic sequence into an array, and as successful keystrokes match you move forward in the array. If you get to the end, then it's Egg time.

**edit** exactly as @EndangeredMassa wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(window).keypress(function(e) {
    var input = $("#input");
    input.val(function(i, v) { return v + String.fromCharCode(e.which) });

    if(input.val().indexOf('colors') > -1) {
      alert('Easter Egg');
      input.val('');
    } 
    else if('colors'.indexOf(input.val())) {
      //Clear value, they've hit another key
      input.val('');
    }        
  });
 });
</script>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

It keeps track of the current portion of colors you've typed in a textbox easy for debugging, just add a `style="display: none;"` when you're done testing.