# Detecting the pressing of a number key for an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, key

I am trying to make a game where the right combination of numbers gives the player an effect to help them pass the level. My plan for doing this was using if statements to test for the key being pressed and change variables accordingly. This should be very simple, but my attempts have failed miserably, while I cannot find any pages that adequately explain this. So, does anyone know how I can detect the press of a number key for an if statement in javascript?

Comment: can you post the code you have so far? is anything working?

Comment: This library might be a good place to start, or maybe even leverage - https://github.com/namuol/cheet.js

Comment: you didnt look at all did you? I just did and found like 50 questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297524/javascript-jquery-keypress-logging

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to enter some particular sequence of numbers, you'll need to use a cache and check each keystroke. Here is an example below. I have indicated that I want 1, then 2, then 3 in that order. Doing it wrong resets the sequence. Completing it also, in this case resets too.

Try it out. run it and pres 1, then 2 then 3. Interrupting the sequence means you must restart.

```js
//press 1, then 2 then 3
var code = [49, 50, 51]
var cache = [];

function checkCode(eve) {

    var keycode = eve.keyCode || eve.which;

    if(keycode === cache.shift()){

      if(!cache.length){
        //resets if you did it. do not include if you want once.
        replenishCache();

        //do whatever you do here.
        doThing();
      }

    } else {
      replenishCache();
    }
}

function doThing(){
    alert('sequence entered');
}

function replenishCache(){
    cache = code.slice(0);
}

replenishCache();

window.addEventListener('keypress', checkCode, false);
```

I will add that this code is totally not in the context of any framework, or module or pattern. I just attached an event to window to illustrate. You'll need to think about how to migrate this into whatever you are doing. For example, rather than just calling a more global function directly `doThing` in this case - you should probably pass that into some sort of plugin or module. Same thing with the sequence of character codes.